# Using recursion to solve mazes in C++?

Tags: c++, recursion, maze

I'm trying to create a program that can solve mazes through recursion. I'm basing my code on a few steps that can be found online, specifically:

1. if (x,y outside maze) return false
2. if (x,y is goal) return true
3. if (x,y not open) return false
4. mark x,y as part of solution path
5. if (FIND-PATH(North of x,y) == true) return true
6. if (FIND-PATH(East of x,y) == true) return true
7. if (FIND-PATH(South of x,y) == true) return true
8. if (FIND-PATH(West of x,y) == true) return true
9. unmark x,y as part of solution path
10. return false

I have seen at least two other questions with this algorithm, but I'm pretty sure the problems weren't exactly the same.

```
bool path (string maze[], int x, int y){
    values val;
    bool check;
    //for (int k=0; k<val.xDim; k++) cout<<maze[k]<<endl;
    cout<<x<<":"<<y<<endl;
    if (x>val.xDim || y>val.yDim || x<0 || y<0) {cout<<"end\n"; return false;  }
    if (maze[x][y]=='x') return true;                           //If exit is reached
    if (maze[x][y]=='%' || maze[x][y]=='+') return false;       //If space is filled
    maze[x][y]='+';
    if (path(maze, x-1, y)==true) return true;
    cout<<"endtwo\n";
    if (check=path(maze, x, y+1)==true) return true;
    if (path(maze, x+1, y)==true) return true;
    if (path(maze, x, y-1)==true) return true;
    maze[x][y]='.';
    return false;
}

int main(){
    if (path(maze, val.startX-1, val.startY)==true) {
        for (int k=0; k<val.xDim; k++) cout<<maze[k]<<endl;
    } else cout<<"No solution found.\n";
}
```

The sample maze is (where e is the entrace and x is the exit):

```
%e%%%%%%%%%
%...%.%...%
%.%.%.%.%%%
%.%.......%
%.%%%%.%%.%
%.%.....%.%
%%%%%%%%%x%
```

Output:

```
-1:1
end
No solution found.
```

From what I can tell, the path method should begin by checking the space directly above the entrance, which is out of the maze (returning false). Following this, it should check east (and so on). However, when I run it, the function returns false and fails to continue onto the following if statements. This is shown by the fact that "end" is printed, while "endtwo" (found after the north check) is not. I'm not sure if there's some form of problem with my recursion logic or my implementation of recursion, so I'm hoping on some clarification on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I feel this question is best suited for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @anakata- I don't think that site is appropriate for this question, since those sites are usually geared toward programming puzzles / shortest solutions to a problem, whereas this is a programming / debugging problem.

Comment: The website is http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/alg/maze/.
From what I understand, the algorithm checks whether there's a path available to the exit from any specific point in the maze.

Comment: what is values val? It looks like it's declared and used, but never initialized

Comment: Oh, sorry. values is just a class that contains a few integers.
I'm not too experienced with using inheritance, so I put the dimensions and start position as public integers in "values" to avoid passing to many values to path.

Comment: ok mmm...is -1:1 a valid starting position?

Comment: The starting position is 0:1, but the first check it makes is -1:1 (checking north of position x:y).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first check in `bool path(...)` finds x<0 since x==-1, so the function returns `false` and exits, and the main program gets a `false` result from the call to `path`, prints what he has to and exits.

You should start your checks with a valid position.

Comment: Of course that doesn't mean the rest of the algorithm is fine :P
I didn't test it!

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. I checked everything else but didn't realize that my original call was incorrect. I don't even remember why I had -1 there in the first place. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are starting from an invalid position, So instead of this `if (path(maze, val.startX-1, val.startY)==true) {`, try this `if (path(maze, val.startX, val.startY)==true) {`. Actual recursion part seem alright to me, provided that you do not mind replacing `'e'` from the maze with a `'.'`.